# What do you call the linguistic ambiguity in an assertion "Blah is the Best X?

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity

I don't know the correct name of the following characteristic or phenomena to search for it on Google for further study and exploration:

> Someone says they live in the "Best Democracy" and they says that they
>   can back this up with historical and contemporary evidence. They could
>   be asserting either:
>
> 1. Their country is the best implementation of democratic principles and this is what they have evidence for; **or**
> 2. They live in country considered sufficiently democratic *and* that country is the proven best in some other way (affluence/power/stability/happiness index/BMI/trombone players/etc).

In more generalised terms:

> An assertion `Best X` could mean:
>
> 1. Best at X; **or**
> 2. A member of X which is Best at Y

**What is this form of linguistic ambiguity called?**

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there's a more specific term than simply _ambiguous_?

Comment: Because the word *ambiguous* is ambiguous. And I assume linguists prefer to avoid infinite [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) when talking to each other.

Comment: Grice's maxims surely come into play here. You wouldn't say "this is the highest bridge" if you actually meant something else. https://effectiviology.com/principles-of-effective-communication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a specific term for this type of ambiguity. I would actually argue that the generic form you present is not inherently ambiguous:

> Spot is the best dog.
>
> Spot is the best dog at running.

These two sentences have drastically different meanings and I do not think it is accurate to suggest that the former could ever imply the latter without *some* additional context.

The only time it is ambiguous is when the object holds some specific quality:

> I am in the best class!

This either describe (a) a group of people who are "the best" or (b) a specific course that is "the best". This ambiguity is nothing more than a word having two meanings that both satisfy the semantic requirements of the sentence.

Another example of this problem:

> "I ran out of the doors," said the carpenter.
>
> "I ran out of the doors," said the athlete.

One of the most famous variants has its own [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_flies_like_an_arrow;_fruit_flies_like_a_banana):

> Time flies like an arrow. Fruit flies like a banana.

Unfortunately for you, the most relevant description of this phenomenon is syntactic ambiguity:

> [Syntactic ambiguity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity), also called amphiboly or amphibology, is a situation where a sentence may be interpreted in more than one way due to ambiguous sentence structure.

Comment: Interesting. I think *Syntactic Ambiguity* (a variant of Szonye's suggestion) and *Zero Copula* might converge on the right description of the phenomena (reading the associated Wikipedia articles). Perhaps the phrase "Best Democracy"/"Best X" can be considered a rhetorical zero-copula contraction/newspaper headline that induces syntactic ambiguity. I think this is more likely than semantic ambiguity (polysemy) as both words ("Best" and "Democracy") aren't especially ambiguous in themselves, but extra words for specificity have perhaps been deliberately omitted for rhetorical benefit.

Comment: There is some syntactic ambiguity in *"Spot is the best dog"*. Say two farmers were chatting on a porch and one points at his dog and said "Spot is the best dog" and yet Spot is visibly crippled. Visual context resolves what "Best Dog" means for this farmer. But the same sentence by phone (when the other farmer has never seen Spot) will imply something quite different. What if Spot is healthy and fit but the setting is now a phone call or a dog racetrack? So yes, the probabilities are not evenly weighted, but some syntactic ambiguity can still exist depending on prior cultural assumptions.

Comment: That's what I meant when I said that "Spot is the best dog" is not ambiguous *without some additional context*.